# Arduino stops working after some receivings from RF

Tags: spi, timers, nrf24l01+, rf

I made a sketch that receives an rgb code from a remote Arduino using nrf24l01 and while it works **for the first receivings** then it stops working. I placed a testing `Serial.println` in the loop to test if Arduino stops to work completely or it doesn't receive any other data. Finally, I understood that it continues to work but it doesnt receive more data. Bellow is my code:

```cpp
#include <RF24Network.h>
#include <RF24Network_config.h>
#include <Sync.h>

#include  <TimerOne.h>
#include <SPI.h>
//#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
RF24 radio(8,10);
RF24Network network(radio);
volatile int i=0; 
volatile int d=0;     // Variable to use as a counter
volatile boolean zero_cross=0;  // Boolean to store a "switch" to tell us if we have crossed zero
int AC_pin= 4;    // Output to Opto Triac pin
int dim = 0;  // Dimming level (0-128)  0 = ON, 128 = OFF
int freqStep = 65; 

struct payload_rgb
{
  unsigned int red;
  unsigned int green;
  unsigned int blue;
};
struct payload_lightuv
{
  unsigned int light;
  unsigned int uv;
};
RF24NetworkHeader header;
payload_rgb payloadrgb;
payload_lightuv payloadl;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(AC_pin, OUTPUT);// Set AC Load pin as output
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);// Set AC Load pin as output
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  attachInterrupt(0, zero_cross_detect, RISING);  // Choose the zero cross interrupt # from the table above
  Timer1.initialize(freqStep);                      // Initialize TimerOne library for the freq we need
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(dim_check, freqStep);    
  Serial.begin(115200);
  radio.begin();
  network.begin(90,01);
}


void loop() {
  network.update();
  while ( network.available() )
  {
    Serial.println("Rec");

    network.peek(header);
    if(header.type=='r'){
      network.read(header,&payloadrgb,sizeof(payloadrgb));
      analogWrite(6,payloadrgb.red);
      analogWrite(9,payloadrgb.green);
      analogWrite(5,payloadrgb.blue);
    }
    if(header.type=='l'){
      network.read(header,&payloadl,sizeof(payloadl));
      dim=payloadl.light;
    }
}
Serial.println("!"); //this is the test println
}
void zero_cross_detect() {    
  zero_cross = true;               // set the boolean to true to tell our dimming function that a zero cross has occured
  i=0;
  digitalWrite(AC_pin, LOW);       // turn off TRIAC (and AC)
}   
void dim_check() {                   
  if(zero_cross == true) {              
    if(i>=dim) {                     
      digitalWrite(AC_pin, HIGH); // turn on light       
      i=0;  // reset time step counter                         
      zero_cross = false; //reset zero cross detection
    } 
    else {
      i++; // increment time step counter                     
    }                                
  }                                  
}}
```

Additionally, this Arduino controls an ac dimmer. Bu I have not done it yet.
How can I fix the problem without removing any feature?

Comment: Is it maybe running out of memory? I am not familiar with network.read but does this memory get free'd ?

Comment: Why network.read should use memory? The only thing that uses memory are the variables and structures. And even if it used, shouldn't the arduino stop completely?

Comment: I think it would have to buffer that input and if it is allocating memory each time and not cleaning up, maybe its running out. But this is just a guess. ..."If you run out of SRAM, your program may fail in unexpected ways; it will appear to upload successfully, but not run, or run strangely"...http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Memory

Comment: So that would be library's problem?

Comment: It's not likely, I thought there was something that you needed to call to free it but it doesn't seem to be the case. Don't you need to declare the variables that are modified in the interrupts as volatile?

Comment: Will that solve the problem?

Comment: Try reducing memory footprint, see if that helps.

Comment: Try resetting the nrfs with the below answer: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/54604/35167

Comment: See this. https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/55042/how-to-automatically-reset-the-nrf24l01-with-code