# How to automatically reset the nrf24l01+ with code?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, communication, nrf24l01+

I have two separate nrf24l01+ connected to two different Arduino UNOs, one as TX and the other as RX. The problem is the connection stops after a while between them.

On the Arduino COM screen I have noticed these things:

**TX Side:** Completely Frozen (Transmission Stops).
**RX Side:** Continuously receives the last data repeatedly.

The problem is solved temporarily when the TX MCU (hence the nrf) is restarted .Sometimes even after restarting the TX MCU the RX stops responding and I have to restart the RX as well. Therefore I am trying to find a way to reset my nrfs automatically using software when this situation occurs.

Comment: What is connected on pin9 and pin10 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem occurs because the transmitter is expecting acknowledgment from the receiver which is getting lost somehow, while transmission and the transmitter still waits for ack for the last transmitted data (which it never gets) so it keeps on transmitting the last packet again and again. I saw on forums that its because of the TX buffer getting full after 3 retries or something. I don't exactly know why it happens.

I first tried resetting just the transmitter through code but it was not enough (as already mentioned in the question). So I now reset both the TX and RX using the below code. I have a separate 1 byte reset-counter in the first byte of the array (you may use a single byte variable) which acts as an id for the packet (you may use the internal PID as well).

The below code resets  the **TX** if **transmission fails** by checking the **return value** of `write` function and resets the **RX** when it **receives the same ack** or packet (with the same reset-counter value) **more than 2 times** (I use a condition to check if the last counter value is different from the current one or not). To reset it using code I use the below algorithm :

1. **Power Down** the NRF using `powerDown()` function.
2. **Re-initialize** the nrf for the MCU.
3. **Power Up** the NRF using `powerUp()` function.

**Note:** I am using TMRH20 RF24 Library.

**TX Code**

```
void radio1_init()
{
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
  myRadio1.begin();
  delay(100);
  myRadio1.setChannel(96);
  myRadio1.setPALevel(POWERLEVEL);
  myRadio1.setDataRate(DATARATE);
  myRadio1.setAutoAck(1);
  myRadio1.enableAckPayload();
  myRadio1.enableDynamicPayloads();
  myRadio1.setRetries(2, 10);
  myRadio1.setCRCLength(RF24_CRC_8);
  myRadio1.openWritingPipe( addresses1[0]);
}

void loop()
{
  dataTransmitted[0]++;
  if ( myRadio1.write( &dataTransmitted, sizeof(dataTransmitted)))
  {

    if (myRadio1.isAckPayloadAvailable())
    {
      myRadio1.read(&ack, sizeof(ack));
    }
  }
  else
  {
    myRadio1.powerDown();
    \\Serial.println(" 1 Tx1 problem end");
    radio1_init();
    myRadio1.powerUp();
  }
}
```

**RX Code**

```
void radio2_init()
{
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
  myRadio2.begin();
  delay(100);
  myRadio2.setChannel(96);
  myRadio2.setPALevel(POWERLEVEL);
  myRadio2.setDataRate(DATARATE);
  myRadio2.setAutoAck(1);
  myRadio2.enableAckPayload();
  myRadio2.enableDynamicPayloads();
  myRadio2.setRetries(10, 10);
  myRadio2.setCRCLength(RF24_CRC_8);
  myRadio2.openReadingPipe(1, addresses2[0]);
  myRadio2.startListening();
}

void loop()
{
      if (myRadio2.available())
      {
        myRadio2.read( &dataReceived, sizeof(dataReceived));
        myRadio2.writeAckPayload(1, &ack2, sizeof(ack2));
        if (prevack2 == dataReceived[0])
        {
          \\Serial.println("RX 2 problem");
          c2++;
        }
        prevack2 = dataReceived[0];
        if (c2 > 2)
        {
          myRadio2.powerDown();
          radio2_init();
          myRadio2.powerUp();
          c2 = 0;
        }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use standard arduino pin cables, then they do not provide stable connectivity for NRF24L01+. Try to solder pins instead (not kidding).

Another reason could be that one of your modules has bad power supply. Power it with perfect 3.3 volts (from another power source, not from Arduino), or use "base module" for the NRF24L01+ (connect this "base module" to 5V pin on Arduino)
http://www.yourduino.com/sunshop/index.php?l=product_detail&p=467

Answer (score 1):

If the NRF24L01 truly locks up, as can happen with an inadequate power supply, then the powerDown(), init(), powerUp() method wont work as the NRF wont receive SPI commands.
In this situation, which seems to be the most common form of lockup, a physical power cycle is the only option.